# Get n level parent with find command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to find my n-th level parent with the find command,
initially, when used this command, it gives me the whole file path:

```
Modified_files_users="$(find /var/lib/abcccc/tamm/acb-Beta-DB-abcc/abc-central/src/main/taff/com/hifinite/components/user
    -type f -mtime -5;)";
```

Output:

```
/var/lib/abcccc/tamm/acb-Beta-DB-abcc/abc-central/src/main/taff/com/hifinite/components/user/file/foo.ext
```

Hence I used the basename GNU with find, but it only gives the file name.

```
 Modified_files_users="$(find /var/lib/abcccc/tamm/acb-Beta-DB-abcc/abc-central/src/main/taff/com/hifinite/components/user
        -type f -mtime -5 -exec basename \{} \;)";
```

Ouput:

```
foo.txt
```

but the Output I expect is

```
/file/foo.ext
```

Is there any way I can get this by adding anything to the -exec command?
basically either I should be able to specify the nth parent which should be included in the output OR) find the whole path after

```
/var/lib/abcccc/tamm/acb-Beta-DB-abcc/abc-central/src/main/taff/com/hifinite/components/user
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `printf` with `%P`:

```
find somedirectory -type f -printf '%P\n'
```

Document:

```
%P     File’s name with the name of the command line argument under which it was found removed.
```

Example:

```
$ find /home/abc/temp -type f
/home/abc/temp/A2018001.txt
/home/abc/temp/myfiles.zip
/home/abc/temp/org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher$PrefixMatchingArchiveFilter.class
```

With printf %P:

```
$ find /home/abc/temp -type f -printf '%P\n'
A2018001.txt
myfiles.zip
org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher$PrefixMatchingArchiveFilter.class
```

Comment: But doesn't OP want the directory name one level before?

Comment: No. The last line he tells he wants everything after that particular path, and the same path is what he has specified in the find.

Comment: As per the OP's description, the whole path after `user` should be `/file/foo.ext` and not just `foo.txt`

Comment: @VikasMishra: Your original requirement in the question did not make sense. You said you needed one path above the original file, e.g. like `file/foo.txt`